# Regexp to match the whole string if there is/isn't a specific number in it

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a way to have a regexp match a whole delimited string in case it fulfils one of the conditions:

1. The string should not contain number 1 (as a single digit, not 11 or 12)
2. The string contains number 1 (as a single digit, not 11 or 12)

The strings can be like the following format:

```
1,2,wo,9,5
1
wo,1,11
```

I have tried the following regexp:

```
/^.*\b(1)\b.*$
/^((?!1).)*$
```

I am trying to match the whole string and I would like to substitute the whole string if one of the conditions is met.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and how it failed for you. That way, we can give an answer that is on point.

Comment: The second sentence is not clear.

Comment: The second sentence is contradicting itself

Comment: If you are searching for strings with/without 1, why are you using regexes that search for 9?

Comment: What flavour of regex?

Comment: @leo just a typo, sorry for the confusion. The problem is that I am trying to replace the whole string if I find an occurrence of 1, and so far I have only been able to replace the 1, and I would have something like, true, 2,wo,9,5 instead of replacing the whole string with true

Comment: @nick Javascript regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will find all strings which have an occurrence of `1` as a single digit:

```
/^.*\b1\b.*$/
```

When you find a match, you can replace the whole string with the word `'true'` using `String.replace`:

```js
const strings = ['1,2,wo,9,5','1','wo,1,11'];
strings.map(s => console.log(s.replace(/^.*\b1\b.*$/, 'true')));
```

If you just wanted to replace the `1` with something, you could use a much simpler regex `/\b1\b/`. To replace all occurences, use the `g` flag:

```js
const strings = ['1,2,wo,1,5','1','wo,1,11'];
strings.map(s => console.log(s.replace(/\b1\b/g, 'true')));
```

If you want to find strings that don't include `1` as a single digit, you can use a negative lookahead i.e.

```
^(?!.*\b1\b.*$).*$
```

and again use `String.replace` to replace the whole string with something e.g.

```js
const strings = ['1,2,wo,9,5','1','wo,1,11','45,x,z,23'];
strings.map(s => console.log(s.replace(/^(?!.*\b1\b.*$).*$/, 'false')));
```

Comment: @revo for the first case, it's essentially the same unless there was more than one occurrence of 1. But I don't think the first case is actually what OP wanted anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly, I would please have just one more thing. I am using javascript here and I am applying the regexp like this:

"regexp": "^(?!.*\b1\b.*$).*$", is there a way to escape the "\"?

Comment: @Site you can escape the \ with \, i.e. `"^(?!.*\\b1\\b.*$).*$"`.